# About the integral $\displaystyle \int_{T_0}^{T_1} \frac{a-f(x)}{T_1-x} d x$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, optimization

Let $[T_0,T_1]\subset \mathbb R^+$, $a>0$.

I am interested in the integral

$$\int_{T_0}^{T_1} \frac{a-f(x)}{T_1-x} d x$$

where $f: [T_0,T_1] \rightarrow \mathbb R^+$ is continuous, such that the above integral converges, $f(T_1)=a$, $f(T_0) <a$, $f$ is increasing.

What can be said about such an $f$ besides that $f(x)$ must go to $a$ faster than $T_1-x$ diverges? Is it necessarily convex/concave? Something else?

Is there a way to find $f$ that minimizes $\displaystyle \int_{T_0}^{T_1} \frac{a-f(x)}{T_1-x} d x$ while satisfying the above conditions?

Comment: The first thing you should do to make your life simpler is assume without loss of generality that a=T1=0.

Comment: @Funktorality $a$ cannot be $0$, neither can $T_1$. We can choose $T_0=0, T_1=1$.

Comment: The point of your question isn't changed by making these assumptions. The problem is translation symmetric in the domain and range. An equivalent question which is more clear is "what are the conditions on $f$ so that $\int_0^1f(x)/xdx$ converges?"

Comment: @Funktorality I do not agree. If $a=0$, then $f=0$ under the above conditions.

Comment: You missed the point of Funktorality suggestion. Read carefully the suggestion.

Comment: @jjagmath Indeed there must be something I am missing. If $f(T_0)=0, f(T_1)=0, f$ positive increasing, then $f=0$ and and integral is $0$.

Comment: In the integral, make the variable substitution $x = T_1 + (T_0-T_1)s$, then $$\int_{T_0}^{T_1} \frac{a-f(x)}{T_1-x}\, dx = \int_0^1 \frac{a-f(T_1+(T_0-T_1)s)}{s} \, ds$$ Now call $g(s) = a-f(T_1+(T_0-T_1)s)$. Then the integral is $$\int_0^1\frac{g(s)}{s}\,ds$$ with $g(0)=0$. Analyzing $g$ is the same that analyzing $f$ since they are connected by affine transformations, which are perfectly understood.

Comment: @jjagmath I definitely agree with that. But this is not the same as setting $a=0$ as per my last comment (and you didn't do that).

Comment: That's why Funktorality didn't say "set $a=0$", but **" assume without loss of generality that $a=0$"**

Comment: @jjagmath again, we cannot assume $a=0$ without loss of generality because the problem becomes trivial. $a=0$ forces $f=0$ so it is a none problem. There are very strict conditions on $f$ in my question. We loose all the generality by assuming $a=0$.

Comment: "Without loss of generality" here means that we may reduce the problem to similar problem in which **the corresponding value** of $a$ is $0$.

Comment: Would people stop [abusing](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730) `\displaystyle` ever?..